# What is the official name of this construct?

Tags: python

In python:

```
>>> a = b or {}
```

Comment: and perl if I recall correctly

Comment: Does everything need to have a special name?

Comment: it helps, when you need to explain it to someone.

Comment: @gnibbler: +1; why does it need a "special" name?  It's the `shortcut or` operator.  What more naming does it need?  @Stefano Borini: Names are not explanations; some names are so opaque ("lambda", the "gamma" function) as to create no value in the name at all.

Comment: @S.Lott : because when you explain something to someone, and this person is taking notes, he would like to have something he can google for, later on, if he does not understand and needs to review the concept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it has an official name, it's just a clever/lazy way to be concise. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
a = b if b else {}
```

or:

```
if b:
    a = b
else:
    a = {}
```

I wrote this as a comment but I think it's worth mentioning here:

You have to be very careful when using this trick. If your intention is to set a default value when something is None, it would be better to write that `is None` test explicitly than use this trick. The reason is that None is not the only thing that evaluates to false in a boolean context. 0, [], {}, ... also evaluate to false. So this trick might not give you the expected results if you didn't think about these special cases.

Here's one way to do it that is safer:

```
a = b if b is not None else {}
```

Comment: Pretty much like var a = b ?? new b() in C#.

Comment: @Filip: Similar, except the null-coalescing operator `??` was added to C# intentionally for that purpose. This trick in Python works because None is treated as false in a boolean context. But 0, [], {}, etc... also evaluate to false, so be careful. If you want to emulate `??`, it's better to write the `is None` test explicitly than rely on this trick.

Comment: It was often combined with related "and" behaviour to get the effect of "a = b if c else d" in the past. The pattern often led to bugs, which is part of the reason for adding the conditional expression. I don't remember what the common edge cases were - that's part of the issue, they aren't obvious.

Comment: @Steve314: The danger with `r = a and b or c` is when a is True but b is 0 the expression evaluates to c instead of 0 as you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `b or {}` is just a simple [boolean OR expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). The special about this is just that this expression does not need return a boolean value per definition like in other languages:

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> (Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because `not` has to invent a value anyway, it does not bother to return a value of the same type as its argument, so e.g., `not 'foo'` yields `False`, not `''`.)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a special construct, at least to my somewhat tired eyes.  It's saying to assign the result of

```
 (b or {})
```

to a.

So, if b is a False value, a gets {} (the empty dictionary literal), otherwise it gets the value of b.

Comment: exactly, but maybe there's a name for it. Short-circuit assignment is the one I would be tempted to say. maybe conditional assignment ? But that normally refers to the ?: operator.

Comment: It's not really relying on any sort of short-circuiting, though... I'd go for that if it was suppressing some side effect on the RHS.  But for this?

Comment: It's a "special construct" if you're coming from C++ or Java where the only things you can put on either side of an "or" are booleans. Here, b could be any object (presumably a dictionary based on the context) so (b or {}) is *not* a boolean. Perfectly normal for a Pythonista, but not obvious if you're learning Python for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

May be [`The expression that return last evaluated argument`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Answer (score 1):

Default Assignment Idiom

Comment: official or invented by you at this very moment ?

Comment: @Stefano, I thought we are voting for what we think the official name should be :)